# $stateParams variable not defined if the view is accessed directly?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have two views VIEW1 and VIEW2. Usually VIEW1 does not need $stateParams vars to function if accessed directly. But if accessed from VIEW2 I need to pass $stateParams vars to VIEW1 from VIEW2.

```
app.controller('View1Ctrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {

   $scope.varView1 = $stateParams.view2Data.varView2;

)}
```

---

```
.state('app.view1', {
  url: '/view1',
  params: {view2Data: null },
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/view1.html',
      controller: 'View1Ctrl'

    }
  }
})
```

---

```
app.controller('View2Ctrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {

  $state.go('app.view1', {view2Data: {varView2: 'varView2 Value' } });

)}
```

The problem is: 
If $stateParams vars are coded in in VIEW1 controller, this will create $stateParams vars undefined problem in case VIEW1 is accessed directly.

I'm thinking of something in VIEW1 controller like `if SET ($scope.varView1 = $stateParams.view2Data.varView2;){ continue }` .

Any solutions for this?

Comment: Please explain why I was given  -1 ?

Comment: Maybe you can show us your routes to make your question clearer

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Why not simply use a different controller for "view2"? Alternatively, wrap a conditional around the data access, eg `$scope.varView1 = $stateParams.view2Data ? $stateParams.view2Data.varView2 : 'some default value';` or even easier, set the default value in the `params` object

Comment: VIEW2 has already a separate controller "View2Ctrl"

Comment: I tried `if($stateParams.view2Data!=null){ $scope.varView1 = $stateParams.view2Data.varView2; }` But it gives an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state config `params` object lets you set default values so you should probably use something like

```
params: {
    view2Data: {
        varView2: null
    }
}
```

At least then, you won't get an *"undefined is not an object"* error for `$stateParams.view2Data.varView2`.

Comment: I added `cache: false,` otherwise View1 controller was keeping `$stateParams.view2Data.varView2` as null

Comment: @user2985035 Added `cache: false` to what? There is no `cache` property on either state config or `$state.go`

Comment: As follows:  `.state('app.view1', {
      cache: false,
      url: '/view1',
      params: {view2Data:
                  {
               varView2: null
                } 
              },  
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/view1.html',
          controller: 'View1Ctrl'

        }
      }
    })`

Comment: OK, But Its working for me like that !! Otherwise, if i don't use "cache: false",  I should  go to the View1 twice in order to populate the value of the varView2 variable.